# Fixed Position Div, displaying on top of following div

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/0vau6psp/  This is the minimum code required to replicated the error.  I am assuming it has something to do with position:fixed but I can not figure it out.

The problem is resulting in my header being display directly on top of the main content which is causing the main content to not be seen,  I would like the content to display underneath the header.

Any help would be appreciated! Below Is my code as well for reference:

HTML:

```
    <header class="site-header" >
  <div class="header-main" id="header-flow">
    <div class="container-fluid header-cont-top-nav">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 text-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.header-main-->
</header>
  <main class="site-main-content" id="mainscrollcontent">
      <p>
       {{ content_for_layout }}
       Test
       Test Content
       Test Content line 4
       </p>
  </main>
```

CSS:

```
#header-flow {
    border-bottom: #73b2b2 3px solid;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#header-flow li{
display:inline-block;
}
.site-main-content {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `margin-top:` or `padding:` or *style* the next set of HTML elements underneath your `fixed` header, you can add a blank div to achieve this.

```
.block { 
    height: 100px; // customize
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vau6psp/4/). & [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0vau6psp/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding-top` or `margin-top` to your .site-main-content css to bring it down

Comment: Yeah I know, but it seems like there should be a way to do it otherwise, I feel like that is just a temporary fix.  The header seems to have no set height

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the header first in HTML, fixing its position and then main , which is coming under.

So u got these options:

1. Stop Fixing the position of Header. .remove this line.
2. [change the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XS7k.png)
3. position:relative;